# trouble intstalling periodictable module

Tags: python-3.x, windows, installation

based on a previous posting on this website, I went to the python.org site and was able to locate and download the tag containing the periodictable-1.5.0 package, which I then saved in my ....\python\python36-32 directory and extracted on my Windows 7 computer.

Having done that, I attempted to install this package from the command line as instructed in the python documentation

```
...\python356-32> python .\periodictable-1.5.0\setup.py install
```

This appeared to execute an installation script but, when I attempted to import the module, it told me the module did not exist.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Figured it out myself -

Comment: ...\python36-32> python -m pip install .\periodictable-1.5.0